# Python Script Error in Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this following script in here and getting this NameError. I have added path variable in Windows 7.

```
C:\Users\myname>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'script' is not defined
```

This is the script I am trying to run :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, string, time
from socket import *
host = "192.168.0.98"
port = 80
print "Open TCP connections to: %s, port %s" % (host, port)
while (1):
    s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send("abc")    
### test: donot close.  s.close()  
time.sleep(0.1)
print ".",
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You are trying to type filename in interactive python shell (after launching `python`). Try `python script.py` in Windows' `cmd`.

Comment: You have a small typo in your code. You might remove the `,` at the end after the print statement.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `python script.py` instead, from the command prompt *not* from the Python interpreter.

However, if you are in the Python interactive interpretor in the same directory as your script, as **@Tuan333** points out, you can do:

```
>>> import script
```

or

```
>>> from script import something
```

to get access to functions and classes defined in the script (note that it is `script` in this case, not `script.py` because you are treating it as a module). However, as **@ŁukaszRogalski** points out, this is not equivalent to running the script from the command prompt as described above.

Comment: your solution would indeed be ideal. I just want to elaborate a bit more: if you have a script, you can also run it using interactive python interpreter by doing `>>> import script`

Comment: @Tuan333 `import script`, not `script.py`, and this approach is **not equivalent** to running `python script.py` (in general case).

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski ah yes. there should not be `.py` in there. You are right, doesn't work in general, but in some simple case as this example, it should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the script all on one line

```
C:\Users\myname>python C:\path\to\script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to run your script by using this command in command prompt 
 *python [Address of your script]*